# Code Optimization in Ruby On Rails?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, optimization, logic

I am developing an iOS event application's backend in ROR. Events has privacy either it is public or private and I have made one method to check for the privacy of the event. Currently I run a query which returns 10k records and it is calling that privacy methods 10k times, which is really a time consuming process. What should I do to optimize the code?

Below is the scenario:

```
def find_events
 events =  Event.all # It returns 10k records
   events.each do |event|
     search_for_privacy(event)
   end
end 


def search_for_privacy event 

   # Pure Logic
end
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: can you do the call in SQL instead of looping through everything?  Meaning is the search_for_privacy just looking for a flag or two of some sort in the db?  Also, you shouldn't load 10k records you should use pagination if these calls are coming via an API

Comment: No, search_for_privacy method is not looking for a flag. Actually there are four conditions inside this method, if privacy is public then there are two condition and if privacy is private then there 2 conditions. We are not looking just for flag. There is around 30 lines of logic in code.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your `events` table has a column called `public` or `private` which indicates whether or not the event is public. You can then easily find all public events by querying like this:

```
Events.where(public: true)
```

You can go further an define a scope:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :public, -> { where(public: true) }
end

# now you can do:
Event.public
```

If you do NOT have a column for indicating the privacy settings, but for example derive the privacy from a description, it may be appropriate to evaluate this when saving a record:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :update_privacy

  protected

  def update_privacy
    self.public = self.is_private?
  end

  def is_private?
    # pure logic
  end
end
```

The upside of this is that you only have to process all the steps necessary to determine the privacy *once when saving an event*, instead of *every time a user is searching for public/private events*.

(don't forget to add the column in a migration, and in the migration don't forget to set the privacy on EXISTING records)